# how to send email to multiple email addresses

Tags: c#

I am having a problem sending email to multiple email addresses using C#.

```
var email = new EmailMessageApiDto
{
    SendTo = input.SendTo,
    Body = input.Body,
    MailVariables = new List<VariableDictionaryDto>(),
    Recipient = new EmailRecipientDto
    {
        EmailAddress = input.SendTo,
        FirstName = input.SendTo.Split('@').First(),
        LastName = input.SendTo.Split('@').Last()
    },
    SendDateTime = Clock.Now,
    Subject = input.Subject,
    Sender = new EmailSenderDto
    {
        EmailAddress = account.SmtpSettings.DefaultSenderAddress,
        FirstName = account.SmtpSettings.DefaultSenderDisplayName.Split(' ').First(),
        LastName = account.SmtpSettings.DefaultSenderDisplayName.Split(' ').Last()
    },ReplyTo = account.SmtpSettings.DefaultSenderAddress
};
```

Do I need to do some escape for the ";" delimiter:  If so, how?

Comment: Do you mean this mailkit? https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit If so, it should provide a MimeMessage class, where you can `msg.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("Name", "mail@mail.com"))`

Comment: I don't know what library he is using, but it's not MailKit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with the classes you are using, but you can send an e-mail to multiple users using the .Net Framework

```
using System.Net.Mail;

public static void SendMessage(string[] sendTo, string sendFrom, string subject, string messageText, string cc, string attachmentPath)
{
    // Create a new message copying the person who sent it
    using (var message = new MailMessage(sendFrom, sendFrom, subject, messageText))
    {
        // Add each email address to send to.
        foreach (string s in sendTo)
            message.To.Add(new MailAddress(s));

        // Add cc to the message if not blank.
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(cc))
            message.CC.Add(new MailAddress(cc));

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(attachmentPath))
            message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(attachmentPath));

        // Send mail through smtp server.
        using (var client = new SmtpClient("yoursmtpserverhere"))
            client.Send(message);
    }
}
```